# How to Scrape data from site (e.g Newspaper Articles) in Java creating REST Service?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, web

I'm building an standalone application using REST archictectural way(In java) and applying basic filtering operations like Searching,Displaying etc for my project.

Comment: Suggest to first look at some Java library that can parse HTML such as Jsoup...

Comment: I have gone through the library but how to make it in a REST architectural way...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, since you're not showing any effort and have not provided any examples of what you tried so far. This question lacks clarity.